# Como fazer input ser obrigatório?

Tags: php, html

quero fazer que um `input` seja obrigatório, exemplo, peço xxxxx, e a pessoa clica em continuar e erroneo, quero que saia  um texto falando "coloque seu xxxx:"

```
<input type="email" id="user_id" name="user_id" placeholder="" autocomplete="on" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" class="andes-form-control__field" maxlength="120" autofocus="">
```

Comment: required no input

Comment: Caso você queira que o formulário não seja submetida, adicione o atributo `required` no input, entretanto se você quiser exibir alguma mensagem de erro terá que utilizar JavaScript.

Comment: eu acho que consegui pq se nao digito nada clicando em avancar nao avanca e se digito algo nada ver ele tbm nao avanca,. se eu fizer um email ele avanca porem como faco que ele exiba uma mensagem de erro falando para colcoar o email? – marceloquiroga 2 mins atrás    Editar    Remover

Answer (score 2):

para ficar claro o input ficaria assim:

```
<input type="email" required id="user_id">
```

Lembrando que para ser validado precisa está dentro de um form

Coloquei o required em outra posição para exemplificar que pode ser em posição diferente.

Comment: adiciono o required no final de todo o codigo que coloquei? ou crio um imput novo como voce colocou en cima..

Comment: Você vai adicionar o required. Pode ser em qualquer posição na verdade. <input required type="email" id="user_id">

Comment: eu acho que consegui pq se nao digito nada clicando em avancar nao avanca e se digito algo nada ver ele tbm nao avanca,. se eu fizer um email ele avanca porem como faco que ele exiba uma mensagem de erro falando para colcoar o email?

Comment: se o tipo do input for  type="email"  ele vai falar que o que foi digitado não é válido, se number valida também e assim vai

Comment: Não esqueça de avaliar a resposta :)

Comment: ele esta como email mas nao aparece nenhum erro apenas nao prosegue..

Comment: Entendi, qual navegador você está usando?